# How to call serial port data when applying AMPD algorithm in pycharm

Tags: python, arduino, wave, myo

The python code is as follows.
Obviously,this algorithm is able to work when the waveform/data is certain.
I wonder how to call the data collected by the arduino and apply it to this algorithm in real time.

```
import numpy as np

def AMPD(data):
    p_data = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=np.int32)
    count = data.shape[0]
    arr_rowsum = []
    for k in range(1, count // 2 + 1):
        row_sum = 0
        for i in range(k, count - k):
            if data[i] > data[i - k] and data[i] > data[i + k]:
                row_sum -= 1
        arr_rowsum.append(row_sum)
    min_index = np.argmin(arr_rowsum)
    max_window_length = min_index
    for k in range(1, max_window_length + 1):
        for i in range(k, count - k):
            if data[i] > data[i - k] and data[i] > data[i + k]:
                p_data[i] += 1
    return np.where(p_data == max_window_length)[0]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sim_data():
    N = 1000
    x = np.linspace(0, 200, N)
    y = 2 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * 300 * x) 
    return y

def vis():
    y = sim_data()
    plt.plot(range(len(y)), y)
    px = AMPD(y)
    plt.scatter(px, y[px], color="red")

    plt.show()

vis()
```

I couldn't find a suitable solution for this question.